# R Lmer output - single model summary output for factors with multiple levels

Tags: r, lme4

When using lmer, if the predictors are factors with multiple levels, how can you obtain the coefficients, standard error and t-values across the entire factor, as opposed to for the individual factor levels?

A specific example of this is in [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0010027715300901) paper (see Table 1). The authors report that they use *lmer* on this model: 
lmer(DeterminerRT ~ AgeGroup * Condition * TrialType * Plurality + (1|participant) + (1|target))

Where AgeGroup, Condition, TrialType and Plurality all have 2 levels. However, in their Table of results they report a single *B*, SE and t value across each factor (rather than for each level).

When I run lmer with predictors with multiple levels, I seem to only be able to obtain model information for each *individual* level of each factor.

I have looked at a number of questions that have already addressed similar themes. Specifically, [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33709/interpreting-the-regression-output-from-a-mixed-model-when-interactions-between), [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/338303/interpreting-output-from-lmer) (which seems like almost the opposite problem) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115065/mixed-repeated-measure-model-specification-and-results-interpretation-using-lme/115082#115082). However, I do not seem to have found the answer so far...

What I am after seems to more closely resemble the output of the anova(lmer) - but I just need it to include the model summary information, rather than the analysis of variance information.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The paper is behind a paywall. Anyway, you are asking for the impossible. Factor variables are transformed to dummy variables. You can get an SE for the coefficients estimated for these dummy variables (which is what summary gives you) but not for the coefficient for the whole factor (because that doesn't exist).

Comment: However, if you only have two levels, there is only one dummy variable and only one coefficient per factor.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I see what you are saying and I think that makes sense... I'm just a little confused about how they present it in this paper as they do seem to present model summary info per factor.

Comment: As far as I know the paper is available here and should be accessible (the table I refer to is towards the end of the document, page 52): https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Cynthia_Fisher7/publication/283323248_Where_are_the_Cookies_Two-_and_Three-year-olds_use_Number-Marked_Verbs_to_Anticipate_Upcoming_Nouns/links/5a959105aca2721405693956/Where-are-the-Cookies-Two-and-Three-year-olds-use-Number-Marked-Verbs-to-Anticipate-Upcoming-Nouns.pdf

Comment: It is also here: (Table is on page 74) http://cynthia.lukyanenko.net/wp-content/uploads/LukyanenkoFisher_inpress.pdf

Comment: Haven't looked in detail, but apparently they only have two-level factors.

Comment: Like C_River, I find it hard to understand why `anova(lm())` provides an "overall" coefficient and P value for a multilevel factor in a linear model (individual levels are accessible via summary(`lm())`), but post hoc testing of  a linear mixed model from `lmer()` using `glht` or `emmeans` provides coefficients and P values only for individual levels.